# Transform event data to projection coordinates - Matplotlib Transformation

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy, coordinate-transformation, map-projections

I have a plot that uses a Cartopy map for its coordinate system. I want to click anywhere on the plot, mark it, and return the location of the clicked point in terms of Latitude and Longitude. **I am just not sure how to transform the event data back to map coordinates**.

I have read through the [Matplotlib Transformations Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html) but it is still unclear to me. The Navigation Toolbar on the plot even displays the coordinates in Lat./Lon but I'm not sure how to access that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Sinusoidal())
ax.set_extent([0,10,0,10], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True,dms=True,x_inline=False,y_inline=False)

def onclick(event): 
    ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    fig.canvas.draw()

    # I want to print xdata and ydata in terms of Latitude and Longitude
    print(event.xdata,event.ydata)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

[image: Example Plot Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the values back to latitude and longitude floats, simply use the `transform_point` method on the `PlateCarree` projection.  Here I formatted the values using the formatters from the gridliner, but you could obviously format how you like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LatitudeFormatter, LongitudeFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
plot_proj = ccrs.Sinusoidal()
data_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=plot_proj)
ax.set_extent([0,10,0,10], crs=data_proj)
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True,dms=True,x_inline=False,y_inline=False)

def onclick(event): 
    ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    fig.canvas.draw()

    # Get hold of latitude and longitude as floats.
    lon, lat = data_proj.transform_point(event.xdata, event.ydata, plot_proj)
    # Format in degrees, minutes and seconds.
    print(gl.yformatter.format_data(lat), gl.xformatter.format_data(lon))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
3°8′39.215″N 2°44′46.914″E
6°41′19.267″N 6°5′21.873″E
2°52′25.117″N 8°46′25.903″E
```